# Method in protected interface within an abstract class not visible to a subclass

Tags: java

If I have

```
public abstract class Test {

    public void foo(){}

    protected interface Test1{
        public void bar();
    }

}

public class NewTest extends Test{
}
```

wondering why `bar()` isn't visible to NewTest though it extends abstract Test? It requires to have NewTest implements Test.Test1. wondering why is that.

Comment: Why would it be? You just **defined** the interface -- `Test` doesn't implement it.

Comment: Show the code that calls `bar` and produces a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

The interface `Test1` is just an interface, whether it's located with the `Test` class or standalone.  The presence of the interface in `Test` doesn't mean that `Test` implements `Test1`, so `NewTest` doesn't implement it either, unless you explicitly implement it with `implements Test.Test1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the interface (`Test1`) `static` to refer to it without an instance of the parent class (`Test`).

For example:

```
public abstract class Test {
  public void foo() {}

  protected static interface Test1 {
    public void bar();
  }
}

public class NewTest extends Test {}
```

Think of this the same way as you would member variables or methods: you can access static members/methods/inner classes if the class is visible; you need an *instance* of the class to access them if the `static` keyword is not used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Test1 class. You need to use this syntax :  `Class.InnerClass`

Here is the example : http://ideone.com/wr5bON

The `Test` class is not implementing the Test1 class.  `foo()`  will not be visible to anyone else unless you implement the interface.